# How to make canvas element in html clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am designing a web page which has a lot of mathematical figures .e.g rhombus ,square ,rectangle,triangle etc....

what I am trying to achieve is ,when I click on any of the figures ,it should show up a msg /info kind of thing.

I have only one canvas id ,and lot of figures in it ,how i make them clickable so that I can display the required info from each figure

Comment: Please provide sample code for the figures.

Comment: You could keep track of the elements in your canvas and then track the mouse: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Comment: The canvas is an *immediate-mode* display. Once painted, its information is lost to the canvas. You need to keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply wrap the canvas id inside  a div element after that you can hide or show the div using js/jquery with that you can display your message

Answer (score 12):

Here's how to use native html canvas to let users get a message about the shape they clicked:

- for each shape, put their corner points in a javascript object
- put all those shape-objects in an array
- listen for mousedown events
- in mousedown check if the mouse is inside each shape using context.isPointInPath
- if the mouse is inside an object, display your message about that shape

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wPMk5/

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    // set styles
    ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
    ctx.strokeStyle="lightgray";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;

    // create a triangle and parallelogram object

    var triangle={
        points:[{x:25,y:100},{x:50,y:50},{x:75,y:100}],
        message:"I am a triangle"
    }

    var parallelogram={
        points:[{x:150,y:50},{x:250,y:50},{x:200,y:100},{x:100,y:100}],
        message:"I am a parallelogram"
    }

    // save the triangle and parallelogram in a shapes[] array

    var shapes=[];
    shapes.push(triangle);
    shapes.push(parallelogram);

    // function to draw (but not fill/stroke) a shape
    // (needed because isPointInPath only tests the last defined path)

    function define(shape){
        var points=shape.points;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
        for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
            ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
        }
    }

    // function to display a shape on the canvas (define + fill + stroke)

    function draw(shape){
        define(shape);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // display the triangle and parallelogram
    draw(triangle);
    draw(parallelogram);


    // called when user clicks the mouse

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      // get the mouse position
      var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // iterate each shape in the shapes array
      for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
          var shape=shapes[i];
          // define the current shape
          define(shape);
          // test if the mouse is in the current shape
          if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
              // if inside, display the shape's message
              alert(shape.message);
          }
      }

    }

    // listen for mousedown events
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to get the x, y coordinates of click with respect to canvas, use:                              

var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      // get the mouse position realtive to canvas
      var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX - rect.left);
      var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY- rect.top);

Answer (score 6):

If you can use SVG instead you can achive this goal very easily. 
Using http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html you can draw relevant shapes and you can get the svg code. Add onclick() events to it .

By this online tool you can create shapes
[image]

Click SVG to get the code

[image]

**Code**

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="74" width="150" y="95" x="58" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <ellipse ry="35" rx="42" id="svg_2" cy="216" cx="158" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <ellipse ry="36" rx="80" id="svg_3" cy="123" cx="342" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#0000ff"/>
  <path id="svg_4" d="m265,257l63,-59l82,47l-22,71l-84,5l-39,-64z" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#0000ff"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

You can add onclick events to this.And also following shows adding **jquery title** mouse over also.

```
 <rect id="svg_29" class="popup_tool" title="Message you want to popup when mouse over" height="17" width="20" y="224" x="452" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff0000"/>
```

Hope you got the answer

Comment: @bjb568 Glad this help you out :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

To easily achieve your task using canvas element you need a framework like [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/)